# Как изменить страну в select country code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при загрузке страницы в select country code была страна United Arab Emirates (+971) и так же в input был код страны без флага??

https://codepen.io/maksam07/pen/ExMrwrY

```
<select id="countrySelect"></select>
<input id="phone" type="tel">

<script>
  var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
  var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
  utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel- 
  input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
  allowDropdown: false,
});

// Заполнение select списка странами из intl-tel-input
var countryData = window.intlTelInputGlobals.getCountryData();
var countrySelect = document.querySelector("#countrySelect");
for (var i = 0; i < countryData.length; i++) {
  var country = countryData[i];
  var optionNode = document.createElement("option");
  optionNode.value = country.iso2;
  optionNode.textContent = country.name + " (+" + country.dialCode + ")";
  countrySelect.appendChild(optionNode);
}

// Синхронизация выбора страны с intl-tel-input
countrySelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
  iti.setCountry(this.value);
});

// Опционально: Обновление select при изменении страны через ввод номера
input.addEventListener("countrychange", function() {
  var currentCountry = iti.getSelectedCountryData();
  countrySelect.value = currentCountry.iso2;
});
```

Comment: Установите параметр `initialCountry`, полистайте в [Initialisation Options](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input?tab=readme-ov-file#initialisation-options)